# Total Commander Automation using Python

Tags: python, search, automation

I wish to search for 500 strings in 2500 .c/.h files and return the `line` and `files` containing the `string`. 
Something that is built in `Total Commander`'s search function. 
Is there a way I can automate the `TC search` and retrieve the results?
Or else can this be achieved in `Python` without `TC`?

Comment: How you input `500 strings and list of files to search`?

Comment: I just input one string and the source path to TC and loop it 500 times.

Answer (score 0):

In Total Commander you can pick menu `Commands->Search in separate Process...`
Then you can filter c/h files using e.g. this mask in "Search for" field: `*.cpp;*.c;*.cxx;*.hpp;*.h;*.hxx` (add/remove which one do you need).
Afterwards you can enable "find text" box and "Regex (2)". And enter your words in text as `(word1|word2|word3)`.
This is also possible to do with Python if you prefer it.